# Strange lights moving North

Tags: identify-this-object

My fiancé and I took our youngest sons out to sky watch at the river near by. The older of the 2 was looking up and said - "look it's Santa's reindeers!" All of us looked up and saw a literal straight line of what looked like hundreds of stars in a straight line, like in a formation, moving due north. They didn't come from the south, it's more like they just appeared and disappeared. Does anyone have any idea what we may have seen?

Comment: More information: eastern Tennessee, about 22:10 eastern time.

Comment: Most likely it's SpaceX's Starlink satellites. For a while they will be lined up like this, until they move to their final orbits. https://vimeo.com/338361997

Comment: Thank you Florin Andrei. That's what it looked like lol.

Comment: Gizmodo: [Breathtaking View of SpaceX Starlink Satellite ‘Train’ Triggers Wave of UFO Sightings](https://gizmodo.com/breathtaking-view-of-spacex-starlink-satellite-train-1835047155)

Comment: @Florin Andrei.  29/05 any chance to see them in line - north of Europe. If so, are their data available to some of the spotting applications and sites? Thx.